# Как правильно реализовать Model\View в QML?

Tags: qt, mvc, qt5, qml

Тест состоит из пунктов (заданий и соответствующих им вариантов ответов):

```
Задание 1
Ответ 1.1
Ответ 1.2

Задание 2
Ответ 2.1
Ответ 2.2
Ответ 2.3
…
```

Класс теста в общих чертах определён так:

```
class Test : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // Пункт теста:
    struct Item {
        // Ответ:
        struct Answer {
            QString content;   // Вариант ответа.
            bool checked;      // Вариант отмечен\не отмечен.
        }; // Answer
        QString task;          // Задание.
        QList<Answer> answers; // Ответы.
    }; // Item
    …
    QList<Item> items;
}; // Test
```

Он зарегистрирован (`qmlRegisterType`) в `main`.

Как правильно реализовать модель, которая бы позволила отображать текущий пункт теста (т. е. задание и варианты ответов с флажками, «запоминая» отмеченные пользователем) в QML? Сам тест хранится в QML-свойстве (`property Test test`) и заполняется данными из заданного файла.

Сейчас я реализовал модель `ItemListModel`, производную от `QAbstractListModel` (для краткости — без разделения на заголовки\реализации методов):

```
class ItemListModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    // Конструкторы:
    explicit ItemListModel (QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QAbstractListModel(parent),
        _items(nullptr)
    {}
    explicit ItemListModel (QList<Test::Item> &items, QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QAbstractListModel(parent),
        _items(&items)
    {}

    // Пункты теста; должны браться из экземпляра Test.
    void setItems (QList<Test::Item> &items) { _items = &items; }
    QList<Test::Item> &items () { return *_items; }

    // Реализация необходимых методов QAbstractListModel
    int rowCount (QModelIndex const & = QModelIndex()) const {
        return _items ? _items->count() : 0;
    }
    QHash<int, QByteArray> ItemListModel::roleNames () const {
        return _role_names;
    }
    QVariant data (QModelIndex const &index, int role) const {
        int row = index.row();
        if (row >= 0 && row < rowCount()) {
            auto const &item = (*_items)[row];
            switch (role) {
            case Qt::DisplayRole:
                return item.task;
            /*case AnswersRole:
                return item.answerListModel();*/
            }
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
private:
    QList<Test::Item> *_items; // Указывает на пункты экземпляра Test
    static QHash<int, QByteArray> const _role_names;
};

QHash<int, QByteArray> const ItemListModel::_role_names = {
    {Qt::DisplayRole, "task"}/*,
    {AnswersRole, "answers"}*/
};
```

Внутри каждого пункта для отображения списка ответов я предполагаю использовать похожий класс `AnswerListModel`, позволяющий редактировать (через метод `setData`) поля `Answer::checked`.

Вопросы:

1. Уместно ли вообще использовать здесь `QAbstractListModel`? Или целесообразнее свести `ItemListModel` и `AnswerListModel` в единую иерархическую модель на основе `QAbstractItemModel`?
2. Как в QML получать данные из зарегистрированных (`qmlRegisterType`) в `main` пользовательских моделей? Завести в классе `Test` свойство либо `Q_INVOKABLE` метод, возвращающий  `ItemListModel *` (а в `Item` соответственно — свойство\метод, возвращающий `AnswerListModel *`)? Вариант с `setContextProperty` не устраивает.
3. Какие роли следует назначить полям? Предполагаю, что `Item::task` и `Answer::content` должны быть `Qt::DisplayRole`, `Answer::checked` — `Qt::CheckStateRole` (а в `setData` — тоже?); нужна ли роль списку ответов (`Item::answers`)?

Конечно же вопросы вызваны моим недопониманием устройства MVC в Qt, но по документации Qt\примерам в интернете мне не удалось найти ответы на них. Заранее спасибо за разъяснения!

**UPD 0** (@maestro): Т. е. метод `data` приобретёт следующий вид?

```
class TestModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    …
    QVariant data (QModelIndex const &index, int role) const {
        int row = index.row();
        return (row >= 0 && row < rowCount())
            ? test.items[row]
            : QVariant();
    }
    …
}
```

Насколько я вижу, ваш пример выведет **все** пункты теста сразу. А мне нужно только текущий. И как в таком случае в QML будет обрабатываться список ответов? Упрощённый пример того, что мне нужно:

```
property int currentItemIndex // Номер текущего пункта теста
…
Text {
    text: test.items[currentItemIndex].task
}
ListView {
    model: test.items[currentItemIndex].answers
    delegate: RadioButton {
        checked: modelData.checked
        text: modelData.content
    }
}
```

Как в таком случае объявить свойство «список ответов»? Я уже делал вариант с `QQmlListProperty` поверх `QList`, он выводил данные, но переключение флажков не сохранял (не было `setData`), да и в документации сказано, что это только для прототипирования. Или надо делать отдельную модель для списка ответов?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос очень обширный и подразумевающий несколько вариантов решения. Я бы предложил такой вариант.

1. `Test`, `Item`, `Answer` реализовать как отдельные классы с поддержкой `Q_OBJECT`.
2. Во всех классах объявить `Q_PROPERTY`, в которых объявить все нужные свойства. Указать спецификаторы доступа `READ`, `WRITE`, `NOTIFY`.
3. Все классы засунуть в макрос `QML_DECLARE_TYPE`.
4. В модели в методе не реализовывать метод `roleNames`. Теперь у нас свойства заменяют роли.
5. В методе `data` выдавать только экземпляр `Item`.

Теперь в делегате QML вы можете обращаться к данным следующим образом.

```
model: test
delegate {
    Text {
        text: test.task;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я дополнил вопрос.